# Adding value automatically to another table when a new value is entered in one table using Stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a table called customer having the foll col:

```
C_id| Acct_no| name| h_add| country| ph_no| company| sal| loan_no| balance|
```

- loan_no = pK

table 2:

```
bank_details2 loan_no| r_interest| loan_amt loan_date| time_yr| intrst
```

`interest` is automatically calculated using a proc (which is successful)

I created another procedure to automatically add loan_no to bank_details2 when loan no is added in customer.

```
create procedure proc_bank2 

as

begin

declare @p as int

--if 

select @p=loan_no from customer where loan_no not in (select loan_no from bank_details2)

return @@rowcount

if @@ROWCOUNT<>0

update bank_details2 set loan_no=@p

end

exec proc_bank2
```

Though creation of procedure is successful,the values are not added.

Can someone pls point out the mistake i made/give solution to this

Comment: The SP will terminate at the `return` and code after that line will not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Return`  every thing is finished and after that wont be executed.
So try this one :

```
create procedure proc_bank2 

as

begin

declare @p as int

--if 

select @p=loan_no from customer where loan_no not in (select loan_no from bank_details2)



if @@ROWCOUNT<>0

update bank_details2 set loan_no=@p
return @@rowcount
end

exec proc_bank2
```

Answer (score 1):

Following on from the answers above, your sp has multiple issues:

```
select @p=loan_no from customer where loan_no not in (select loan_no from bank_details2)
```

will set the value of @p to the last unmatched loan_no it finds regardless of customer.

```
update bank_details2 set loan_no=@p
```

has no where clause so will update every row on the table. I suspect, but am not sure that you really wanted to insert here.

Ideally the proc that adds the loan_no to the customer should add it to the bank_details2 table. If that is not possible the proc proc_bank2 should be rewritten to accept the parameter loan_no which is passed when called by the first proc. you can then check for this loan_no and insert as nesscessary.

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
return @@rowcount
```

returns, meaning it quits the stored procedure without executing the remainder. Remove it.

Comment: @Amirreza i did as u told, but the loan_no in table bank_details2 got replaced by the recently added loanno in customer.  16 10 100 2009-12-12 5 50
16 15 300 2009-11-12 9 405
16 5 200 2009-08-08 7 70
16 15 1500 2009-09-08 5 1125
16 15 1500 2010-10-05 5 1125